# Does ROS navigation stack need wheel encoder?

Tags: ros, navigation, encoder, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a mobile robot without wheel encoder. I have a 2D laser range finder. I want to run ROS navigation on this robot.

I notice that amcl can provide tf between `/map` and `/odom`. Because I have no wheel encoder, so that no `/odom` to `/base_link` tf can be provided.

Does ROS navigation stack need wheel encoder? How can I run the navigation stack on this robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224992/does-ros-navigation-stack-need-wheel-encoder?/) by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2016-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can check [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/49204/using-amcl-without-wheel-odometry-only-laser-imu/) and [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/30124/amcl-without-using-odomedry-but-laser_scan_matcher-instead/).

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2